# Laplace's characterization of Gauss as "a super-terrestrial spirit in a human body"

Tags: biographical-details, reference-request, quote

The following words concerning Carl Friedrich Gauss are attributed to Laplace in an article from the Mathematics magazine by Teets and Whitehead ([The discovery of Ceres: how Gauss became famous](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-discovery-of-ceres-how-gauss-became-famous), first page.)

> The Duke of Brunswick has discovered more in his country than a
>   planet: a super-terrestrial spirit in a human body.

I am looking for the original quote of Laplace, presumably in French, together with a reference.

Comment: I have doubts that the quote is authentic. Teets and Whitehead possibly took it from the [Dunnington-Gray-Dohse's 1955 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=4mwSrfxBSzkC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (p. 44), which only says that Laplace "is said to have exclaimed" this, and without attribution. So even by the anecdote itself there would be no original reference. More disturbingly, I was unable to find anything close to the French translation of this sentence even second hand.

Comment: Another extraterrestrial visited us in 20th century (John von Neumann). I don't remember who said this, but is this really important?